# Why can't I see the "block download" option when sharing some videos on OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive

Sometimes I don't see the "block download" option when sharing some videos on OneDrive:

[image]

Sometimes I do see it:

[image]

Why?

I use a OneDrive account as part of my employer's Office 365 account.